# What's happening when shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation always returns NO?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, undefined-behavior, autorotate

Strange question, but what's happening when some UIViewController doesn't support any orientation? :)

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return NO;
}
```

Which orientation will be supported? What is going to be behavior of that UIViewController?

Comment: As the comment states it will default to portrait, except if you have set some other orientation as default in your plist.

Comment: If I recall this can cause problems if the previous view controller is in landscape and the view is pushed onto the stack. It can be displayed in landscape which might not be what you want.

Comment: Well I mean if you think about it, it makes sense that it reverts to portrait or landscape (just something in general) if you return no, there can't actually be no orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default the orientation is potrait until and unless u have explicitly changed the orientation to landscape.

Answer (score 1):

returned NO from `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` for all interface orientations. It should support at least one orientation.